# Operate multiple arrays simultaneously

Tags: arrays, actionscript-3, adobe

I am using as3 in adobe animate to create a video game. 
I have created multiple arrays with movie clips e.g.

```
var A:Array [mc1, mc2, mc3]
var B:Array [mc4, mc5, mc6]
var C:Array [mc7, mc8, mc9]
var anObject:DisplayObject;
```

How can I operate all movie clips in all arrays simultaneously?
I have tried this:

```
mc_Player.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, Change_Position);
function Change_Position (event:MouseEvent):void
{
    {for each (anObject in A) & (anObject in B) & (anObject in C) // how can I get this right?
    {anObject.x -= 100;
    }}
}
```

I am also trying to understand if there is a way to operate all movie clips in my project simultaneously without using arrays.

e.g.

```
mc_Player.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, Change_Position);
function Change_Position (event:MouseEvent):void
{
    {all movie_clips // how can I get this right?
    {anObject.x -= 100;
    }}
}
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's no such thing as **simultaneous** in programming (well, unless you are multi-threading with the perfect sync, which is not an AS3 story at all).

There are to ways to get close to that **simultaneous** thing:

1. Put all the objects into a single container. You will be able to change **x** and **y** of that container so all the in-laid objects will change their visible positions at once. The downside is that you cannot rotate or scale them individually (think of them as clipped to a board and imagine you rotate the whole board), or you won't be able to move half of them.
2. **Array**s and loops. You iterate through all the items one by one, very fast. It looks **simultaneous** from the outside, but it never is.

All that said, in order to achieve the things you want you need to figure a way to put all the objects you want to process **simultaneously** into a single **Array** and then do the thing you want on them.

**Case №1**: many **Array**s to one.

```
// This methods takes a mixed list of items and Arrays
// and returns a single flattened list of items.
function flatten(...args:Array):Array
{
    var i:int = 0;

    // Iterate over the arguments from the first and on. 
    while (i < args.length)
    {
        if (args[i] is Array)
        {
            // These commands cut the reference to the Array
            // and put the whole list of its elements instead.
            aRay = [i,1].concat(args[i]);
            args.splice.apply(args, aRay);
        }
        else
        {
            // The element is not an Array so let's just leave it be.
            i++;
        }
    }

    return args;
}
```

Then all you need to do is to get a single list out of your several **Array**s:

```
var ABC:Array = flatten(A, B, C);

for each (var anObject:DisplayObject in ABC)
{
    anObject.x -= 100;
}
```

Performance-wise, it is a good idea to pre-organize, if logically possible, these **Array**s so you don't have to compile them each time you need to process all the objects. Simply, if sometimes you would need A + B, and sometimes B + C, and sometimes A + B + C, just create them and have them ready. If you know what you are going to deal with, you won't even need that complicated **flatten** method:

```
var AB:Array = A.concat(B);
var BC:Array = B.concat(C);

var ABC:Array = A.concat(B).concat(C);
```

**Case №2**: all the children at once. As I already explained in [my answer to one of your previous questions](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59510646/4687633), you can iterate over all the children of a certain container, and you can put them into — guess what — **Array** for later use. Also, you can filter the objects while doing so and put only those ones you actually want to be there.

```
var ALL:Array = new Array;

// Iterate over the amount of children of "this" container.
for (var i:int = 0; i < numChildren; i++)
{
    // Obtain a reference to the child at the depth "i".
    var anObject:DisplayObject = getChildAt(i);

    // Here go possible criteria for enlisting.

    // This will ignore texts and buttons.
    // if (anObject is MovieClip)

    // This will take only those with names starting with "mc".
    if (anObject.name.substr(0, 2) == "mc")
    {
        ALL.push(anObject);
    }
}

// Viola! You have all the objects you want in a single Array
// so you can bulk-process them now, which is ALMOST simultaneous.
```

Comment: thanks so much. That was extremely helpful. I have one more question. How can I reset the position of the objects in one array to what they were at the beginning of the game. I would like to do that through a click on a mc. e.g. 
mc_x.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, Change_Position);
function Change_Position (event:MouseEvent):void
{
    {for each (anObject in A)  
    {anObject.x = ORIGINAL POSITION...... Thanks!

Comment: @JudithHuber There's no *resetting*, as the objects do not naturally store the history of their properties being changed. There are two ways about it. 1. You design your app to store the data you need (like, in the very beginning you record the objects' positions), then at any given moment you can position these objects with the stored data. 2. Think on a larger level. Instead of working with a single copy of whatever you have there, work with multiple. When you need to *reset* everything, just destroy the current copy completely and create a fresh one where things are on their initial places.

Comment: Thanks! I'll try that

Comment: @JudithHuber Do you, probably, want me to tutor you in the ways of programming?

Comment: Sry, I am seeing this only now. yea, I could use a bit of support. How can we connect?

Comment: @JudithHuber Email me to thydmitry@mail.ru which messengers do you have/use. Telegram would be ideal, but I can resort to Skype or WhatsApp. FaceBook Messenger too.

Comment: I sent you an email from judith.kr@hotmail.com. Did you get it?

Comment: @JudithHuber Yep, sent you an answer.